# Set Logger levels for JSF MyFaces Renderkit

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, myfaces

I am working on a JSF application using MyFaces implementation. Version is 2.1.1.

I am seeing lot of unnecessary WARNING logs from various renderkits as below:

```
HtmlLabelRend W   Attribute 'for' of label component with id j_id179528215_7af12bd8 is not defined
HtmlGridRende W   PanelGrid j_id179528215_7af12adc has not enough children. Child count should be a multiple of the columns attribute.
```

Where and How do I set these logging levels to SEVERE so that my log files are not filed up with these warning messages?

PS: Using `LOGBACK` as logger. Which in-turn used SL4J